# create database jdbc Derby for a portable Database application

Tags: java, database, jdbc, derby

class to create folder and derby database

```
package Utility_Package;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.logging.Level;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import java.sql.Statement;

import java.util.logging.Level;

import java.util.logging.Logger;




     public class systemSetup {

  String finalDirectory;

String dirName = "Car_washing_System";

Connection con = null;

Statement st = null;

public String url;

// method to create Database in the Folder
 public void createDB(){

 try {
     System.setProperty("derby.system.home",
             dirName+"/dbs");

     try {
         Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");

     } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {

         Logger.getLogger(systemSetup.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }

     con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

     st = con.createStatement();

     st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE CARS(ID INT PRIMARY KEY,"
                + "NAME VARCHAR(30), PRICE INT)");
        st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO CARS VALUES(1, 'Audi', 52642)");
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true");

 } catch (SQLException ex) {

  Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(systemSetup.class.getName());

        if (((ex.getErrorCode() == 50000)
                && ("XJ015".equals(ex.getSQLState())))) {

            lgr.log(Level.INFO, "Derby shut down normally", ex);

        } else {

            lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }

    } finally {

        try {

            if (st != null) {

                st.close();
            }
            if (con != null) {

                con.close();
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {

            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(systemSetup.class.getName());

            lgr.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
}

// Method to create the folder on the mac if does not exist 

public File createUserDirectory(){

    // Creating the directories for the java desktop application  
    final File homeDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));

    final File dir = new File(homeDir, dirName);

    if (!dir.exists() && !dir.mkdirs()) {  

        finalDirectory = dir.toString();

        url = "jdbc:derby:"+finalDirectory+ "systemDb;user=USER";

        // verify if folder has been created and then check that url is not null
        if(!url.isEmpty()){
createDB();
} else {createUserDirectory();}

}return dir;
}

}
```

---output 
run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)

the problem is the file compile, folder is created  no problem but no database is created under the folder , please any help will appreciated

Comment: Is a derby.log file created?

Comment: Bryan -- Yes the derby.log is created under my project directory but not under the directory the programme has created

Comment: Is the database also created in the same location as the derby.log (your project directory)? The Derby engine generally creates the derby.log in the directory it considers to be its "home" directory, so I'm wondering if your attempt to control the derby.system.home property is not working. Have you tried running your program with -Dderby.system.home=/your/dbs to see if that works any better?